# Triggered event is received twice. How to find ghost view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I instanciate ChildView a couple of times. In the ChildViews lives a trigger. Once triggered, a function in the parent is called which sets the model. The problem is, the trigger is triggered only once (once I can see, at least), but the parent receives two. I know about ghost views, but how do I find them? I don't work with a global namespace, I use require.js.

```
vParentView = require 'views/parentview'

class vParentView

    render: ->
        view1 = new ChildView()
        view1.on 'data changed', @updateModel, @
        view2 = new ChildView()
        view2.on 'data changed', @updateModel, @
        view3 = new ChildView()
        view3.on 'data changed', @updateModel, @
        etc...

    updateModel: (data) ->
        @model.set data.attr, data.options
```

I removed the context @ to see which view triggered the updateModel() twice, maybe they were from different views, but they weren't. So, the same view triggers updateModel twice.

EDIT:
The code for the ChildView is somewhat uninteresting:

```
vChildView = require 'views/childview'

class vChildView

    events:
        'change input.someclass': 'onChangeInput'
        'change textarea.someclass': 'onChangeInput'

    onChangeInput: (e) ->
        @trigger 'data changed'

    render: ->
        html = _.template tpl

        @$el.html html


        @
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit more of your code would help (like @Brendan Delumpa said)

In situations like yours in which things happen and you do not know why and which triggers them, I normally place a `console.log('')` under each function like so

```
class vParentView

    render: ->
        console.log 'vParentView -> render'
        ...

    updateModel: (data) ->
        console.log 'vParentView -> updateModel'
        ...
```

after this, if I still do not know where the problem is I will add some break points in the `Developer Tools` and step line by line until I will find which is triggering twice the same thing

Comment: That's exactly what I did! That way I found out that the trigger is send only once, but received twice.In the ChildView everything logs as normal. I've also used Developer Tools to step through the code, but it passes updateModel only once. :(

Answer (score 1):

Derick Bailey wrote a great in-depth blog post on this: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/